# Using integer sequences with tuples and variadic templates

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have a tuple:

```cpp
std::tuple<int, char, unsigned int> t{1, 'a', 4}
```

How do I iterate on the types of the above tuple using `std::index_sequence` and friends, so I can use (or re-write if needed) the function `to_token` below?

```cpp
template<typename P1, typename... Param>
std::vector<std::string> to_token(const P1& p1, const Param&... param) {
    const auto to_token_impl = [](const auto& t) {
        using ParamType = std::decay_t<decltype(t)>;
        std::stringstream ss;

        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<ParamType, char>)
            ss << "char";
        else if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<ParamType>) {
            ss << "integral";
        }
        return ss.str();
    };
    return {to_token_impl(p1), to_token_impl(param)...};
}
```

Expected output: `{ "integral", "char", "integral" }`

Based on the examples found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), I've started working on this indirection but I can't wrap my mind around what to do next...

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void tokenize(const std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
    tokenize_impl(t, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void tokenize_impl(const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    // ?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template<typename... Args>
decltype(auto) tokenize(const std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
    return std::apply(
        [](auto const &... o) -> decltype(auto) { return to_token(o...); },
        t
    );
}
```

The lambda is required to defer `to_token`'s argument deduction until it can actually take place inside of `std::apply`, otherwise `to_token` has no definite type and can't be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Wow... okay, missed that apparently! Template deduction fails [in this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a0CT5L) though, any idea why?

Comment: @Fluffy Why, why, *why* do I keep posting answers without testing them first. Fix is on the way...

Answer (score 4):

```
std::string typeToString(int) {
    return "integral";
}

std::string typeToString(char) {
    return "char";
}
// overload this method to support other types

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
auto tokenize_impl(const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::vector<std::string>( {typeToString(std::get<Is>(t))...} );
}

template<typename... Args>
auto tokenize(const std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
    return tokenize_impl(t, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}


int main() {
    auto t = std::make_tuple(1,'a',4);
    auto res = tokenize(t);
    for (auto elem : res)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

as output:

```
integral
char
integral
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ZhNJme)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I failed to write. Thanks!